# IIS 8 - Site not found with localhost or IP address but works with host name?

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a single IIS 8 website bound to an IP address. I can access the site by using the host name (e.g. www.________.com) but not by IP address or localhost. I checked the bindings and made sure that I had a binding without any host name filled in:

[image]

Yet, accessing by IP or localhost returns a 404 page not found error.

Comment: Solved it! Our ASP.NET application was configured to require SSL, but I only had a binding for HTTP with no host name. After adding a binding for HTTPS with no host name, the site now loads.